# Understanding "Pset 2: Caesar" code in CS50

Tags: c, loops, command-line-arguments, cs50

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    if (argc == 2)
    {
        string cmd = argv[1];

        for (int i = 0, n = strlen(cmd); i<n ; i++)
        {
            if (isdigit(cmd[i]))
            {
                continue;
            }
            else
            {
                printf("Usage: %s key \n", argv[0]);
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Usage: %s key \n", argv[0]);
    }
}
```

I am following the CS50 course, and I have gotten to the "Pset2: Caesar" problem. I am able to take the command line argument and check them if they are digits or not.

The problem I am facing, is that after checking the validity of the arguments, I want the program to return that value. I want to check if the given input is numerical only. If it is, I want the program to use that numerical argument value for computing the cipher. The problem is_ I am using a loop to check the input, and I have to use `continue;` I am confused, since if I remove `continue;` the program will fail the task of validating the key.

Example: If I replace `continue;` with `printf("True\n");`, the program prints `TrueTrue` after giving `20` as input. After giving `20x` as input, I get `TrueTrueUsage: ./Caesar key` whereas ideally, it should only return `Usage: ./Caesar key`.

The problem statement link: https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2020/psets/2/caesar/

Comment: @kiner_shah it's this year version of the problem.

Comment: You just need to add `return 1` after `printf` in the `else` block inside the `for` loop. Also, you are not returning any integer from `main` - its return type is `int`.

Comment: No need to print "True". Before there was `continue` statement right? That was correct - you need to use `continue` if `cmd[i]` is a digit. `if (isdigit(cmd[i])) { continue; } else { printf("Usage: %s key\n", argv[0]); return 1; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are complicating the logic of confirming that the first argument to the program is all digits. You really have three tasks:

1. validate that at least one argument is given;
2. loop over the argument to validate each character is a digit;

- if non-digit found, output error, show usage, return `EXIT_FAILURE` (`1`)

3. valid argument -- output key.

While it is perfectly fine to check `(argc == 2)` to require exactly one argument on the command line, it is often helpful to think about what is needed, at minimum. There you need at least one argument, so a check of `(argc < 2)` identifies the lack of an argument, but does not prevent entering more than 1 argument if you take additional optional arguments. For example:

```
    if (argc < 2 ) {    /* validate 1 argument given */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: insufficient input,\n"
                        "usage: %s key (all digits)\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }
```

(**note:** on error, there is no need for an `else` statement. Simply handle the error and exit. That saves a level of indention throughout the rest of your code.)

Validating that each character is a digit requires simply looping over each character and checking with `isdigit()`. You do not need `strlen()`. In C a string is terminated by the nul-terminating character `'\0'` (which has the ASCII value of `0`). To loop over a string, all you need is:

```
    string cmd = argv[1];           /* assing to cmd */
    
    for (int i = 0; cmd[i]; i++)    /* loop over each char in cmd */
        if (isdigit((unsigned char)cmd[i]) == 0) {  /* if non-digit, handle error */
            fprintf (stderr, "error: '%c' is non-digit.\n"
                            "usage: %s key (all digits)\n", cmd[i], argv[0]);
            return 1;
        }
```

(**note:** again, when an error condition requiring exit is reached, there is no need for an `else`, simply handle the error and exit)

Also note the value passed to the `isdigit()` macro (as for all `ctype.h` macros) must have the value of an `unsigned char` or `EOF` so the cast to `unsigned char` is necessary. See [man 3 isalpha](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/isalpha.3.html) (understand that the value of a `char` will always be within `unsigned char`, but build good habits early)

After validating that all characters are digits, all that remains is outputting your key. Putting it altogether you would have:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <cs50.h>

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    
    if (argc < 2 ) {    /* validate 1 argument given */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: insufficient input,\n"
                        "usage: %s key (all digits)\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }
    
    string cmd = argv[1];           /* assing to cmd */
    
    for (int i = 0; cmd[i]; i++)    /* loop over each char in cmd */
        if (isdigit((unsigned char)cmd[i]) == 0) {  /* if non-digit, handle error */
            fprintf (stderr, "error: '%c' is non-digit.\n"
                            "usage: %s key (all digits)\n", cmd[i], argv[0]);
            return 1;
        }
    
    printf ("key: %s\n", cmd);      /* output good key */
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

No argument:

```
$./bin/pset2_ceaser
error: insufficient input,
usage: ./bin/pset2_ceaser key (all digits)
```

Invalid argument:

```
$ ./bin/pset2_ceaser 123foo
error: 'f' is non-digit.
usage: ./bin/pset2_ceaser key (all digits)
```

Good input:

```
$ ./bin/pset2_ceaser 12345
key: 12345
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions, or if I misread your question in any way.

Comment: I modified the code according to what I've learned till now and it works. However, when I try to return the value to main function I get the error `use of undeclared identifier 'key'`. I have completed another problem and haven't faced this error. Honestly, I am new to programming and I don't know how to return a value or declare a function.
The code : <https://codeshare.io/anyv11>

Comment: Yes, you would have to convert what is in `cmd` to an `int` and then return that value. (using `sscanf()` will be easiest for the conversion, but recommend `strtol()` for full error checking of conversion) `"key"` is just part of the `printf` format string, not a declared variable. Additionally, while you can return any value from a function, you only return `0` or `1` from `main()` to your shell. That is why C provides 2 macros, `EXIT_SUCCESS` (`0`) and `EXIT_FAILURE (`1`) for that purpose.

Answer (score 1):

You can break the loop early if the code hits a character that is *not* a digit:

```
   if ( !isdigit( cmd[i] ) )
   {
       printf("Usage: %s key \n", argv[0]);
       break;
   }
```

There's also the function `strtol()` which converts the argument to an integer.  It will handle the errors for you.

```
#include <stdio.h>
//#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    if (argc == 2)
    {
        char *error_at = NULL;

        long rotation = strtol( argv[1], &error_at, 10 );

        if ( rotation == 0 )
        { 
            if ( error_at != argv[1] )
                fprintf( stderr, "A rotation of zero is ineffective\n" );

            else if ( error_at == argv[1] )
                fprintf( stderr, "That's not a number!\n" );

            exit( 1 );
        }
        else
        {
            // Cypher is limited to A-Z
            rotation %= 26;

            printf( "DEBUG: rotation is %ld\n", rotation );
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf ("Usage: %s key \n", argv[0]);
        exit( 1 );
    }

    return 0;
}
```